# How to stop solr with command line

Tags: solr

I want to stop solr by command so if find this article

http://rc98.net/solrinit

```
echo "Stopping Solr"
        cd $SOLR_DIR
        java -Xmx1024m -DSTOP.PORT=8079 -DSTOP.KEY=stopkey -jar start.jar --stop
```

what is Xmx1024m ?

and where i will find DSTOP.KEY ?

**Please tell proper procedure to start and stop solr by command line.**

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`-XmX1024m` - is the java parameter and specifies the maximum java heap size, which in your case is set to 1 GB.

`stopkey` is a secret key on startup which must also be present on the termination request to enhance security.

You can find a detailed explanation @ http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Securing+Jetty

Example -

Starting solr with Jetty -

```
java -DSTOP.PORT=8079 -DSTOP.KEY=mysecret -jar start.jar
```

Stopping Solr with Jetty -

```
java -DSTOP.PORT=8079 -DSTOP.KEY=mysecret -jar start.jar --stop
```

the STOP.KEY is the secret key which should match during the stop command.

Comment: i am not able to do stop with , can u explain in step what i need to do start solr and stop solr ?

Comment: Updated the answer. Kindly take some efforts to go through the simple documentation mentioned in the answer. Its very clearly mentioned there.

Comment: when i run java -DSTOP.PORT=8079 -DSTOP.KEY=mysecret -jar start.jar after stoping solr in example directory it say address already in use and doesn't start the solr  , what can be done

Comment: The commands work fine, and the stop command stops the process and the address in unbound. Check when the stop commond is execute does you jetty stop completely and there is no other jetty process running.

Comment: i have other jetty running in hbase and hadoop so how they can reflect in jetty of solr and why so i stop hbase , how can i proceed

Comment: That may not hinder it as it completely different process. can you check bringing it down, if the normal start stop works ?

Comment: no normal start doesn't then for stop i need to kill the process of start.jar

Answer (score 40):

`solr stop -all` # Stops all the ports

`solr stop -p 8983` # Stop the particular port

If it shows the error `ERROR: Port 8983 is already being used by another process.`, kill the console window which runs Solr by `Ctrl-C` and then try one of the above options. Because killing the console window does not stop the service.

Comment: I like the stop -all approach, note if you are in root folder it would be bin/solr stop -all

Comment: this is the answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

You could run (where 8983 is the default solr port)

```
lsof -i :8983
```

which will return PID#, then use

```
kill -9 PID#
```

to kill that pid (run it without the hash)

Comment: This worked for me as well. Couldn't get accepted answer to work.

Comment: Or: "fuser -k 8983/tcp" (as seen in: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11596144/2265487) And include in .bashrc an alias for ease of use: alias solr_stop='fuser -k 8983/tcp'

Comment: That is a really bad idea!! Why not even let Solr have a chance to shut down cleanly by using `kill` (without `-9`) first. The `STOP.PORT` method is safest, but `kill`ing it normally works fine, too. With `kill -9` you risk a corrupted index and to loose all data.

Comment: Doing this could have bad consequences. Try to close gracefully. Downvoted.

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me if rake sunspot:solr:stop doesn't work

`ps -ef | grep solr`

then using the information returned

`sudo kill <process_id>`

example:

`sudo kill 792`

Comment: You should not kill the process. Try to close gracefully. Solr needs to persist changes and so some cleanup before closing.

Answer (score 1):

For local operation, you can kill the Solr server by pressing `Ctrl-c` in the console window
in which you started Solr. Typically, this is safe enough for development and testing