# How to kill a process running on particular port in Linux?

Tags: linux, unix, port, kill-process

I tried to close the tomcat using `./shutdown.sh` from tomcat `/bin` directory. But found that the server was not closed properly. And thus I was unable to restart
My tomcat is running on port `8080`.

I want to kill the tomcat process running on `8080`. I first want to have the list of processes running on a specific port (8080) in order to select which process to kill.

Comment: possible duplicate of [shell script to kill the process listening on port 3000?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168392/shell-script-to-kill-the-process-listening-on-port-3000)

Comment: Just warning for busybox users: With busybox 'lsof', those proposed `kill $(lsof ...)` commands will kill lot more that you want.

Answer (score 387, accepted):

Use the command

```
 sudo netstat -plten |grep java
```

used `grep java` as `tomcat` uses `java` as their processes.

It will show the list of processes with port number and process id

```
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      
1000       30070621    16085/java
```

the number before `/java` is a process id. Now use `kill` command to kill the process

```
kill -9 16085
```

`-9` implies the process will be killed forcefully.

Comment: You might want to add that one might need root privilegues to get process names via `netstat`.

Comment: @JonasWielicki you can see the ones you own w/out root privileges.

Comment: I needed root privileges for netstat.  Is there a way to actually know what the process came from?  As far as I could tell I had closed all applications but it may have been from a terminal window where I inadvertently pushed the processes to a background task.  Maybe I should have ran the terminal command 'ps' to see all processes first...

Comment: `sudo netstat -plten | grep :8080` will work even when you do not know the application.  This found a ruby process that `lsof -i` did not find for me.

Comment: `netstat` is [the deprecated alternative](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/261224/209677) to [`ss`](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/iproute2). [Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/106562/209677) an example on how to use it.

Comment: possible TOCTOUC issue depending on your use case

Answer (score 1731):

This `fuser 8080/tcp` will print you PID of process bound on that port.

And this `fuser -k 8080/tcp` will kill that process.

Works on Linux only. More universal is use of `lsof -i4` (or 6 for IPv6).

General form:

```bash
# list the TCP process bound to port PORT
fuser PORT/tcp
# Example: list the TCP process bound to port 8080
fuser 8080/tcp

# list the UDP process bound to port PORT
fuser PORT/udp
# Example: list the UDP process bound to port 8080
fuser 8080/udp
```

Comment: does this close a possible connected socket to 8080 as well?

Comment: Of course, all file descriptors are closed when proces finish.

Comment: It does not properly close the port. The port is put into TIME_WAIT state after the parent process is killed. The OS will then eventually completely close the port after about 60 seconds. It means that you can't reuse the port for at least 60 seconds (unless you give the reuse option to the socket).

Comment: On Darwin, must be using a different version of `fuser`. Only takes a file, doesn't support `-k`.

Comment: 'fuser -k -n tcp 8080' will kill the process too

Comment: @dbliss fuser is part of psmisc. In case you get `fuser: command not found`, install psmisc. For CentOS/RHEL 7, run `sudo yum install psmisc`

Comment: There is a TOCTOU issue with using lsof and kill, depending on what you're doing (not an issue in the case of an SSH tunnel you picked the port for and only one instance of your script is running). I'm not sure if fuser avoids it - it may be platform dependent.

Comment: if the task is bind to root user need to run as sudo

Answer (score 1401):

To list any process listening to the port 8080:

```
lsof -i:8080
```

To kill any process listening to the port 8080:

```
kill $(lsof -t -i:8080)
```

or more violently:

```
kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:8080)
```

(`-9` corresponds to the `SIGKILL - terminate immediately/hard kill` signal: see [List of Kill Signals](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/317492/16704) and [What is the purpose of the -9 option in the kill command?](https://askubuntu.com/q/184071/44876). If no signal is specified to `kill`, the TERM signal a.k.a. `-15` or `soft kill` is sent, which sometimes isn't enough to kill a process.).

Comment: kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]
This is what I am getting when I Execute your commands

Comment: @SudhirBelagali did you it with super user `sudo`

Comment: Worked on my Mac as well

Comment: I would like to add that sometimes you do not have permissions to see the process id, in that case you need to do `sudo lsof -i:8080`.

Comment: why the second tips is more violent ?

Comment: @Webman more violently means it kills my web browser at well :( Here is the best solution from Gal Bracha: kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:3000 -sTCP:LISTEN)

Comment: @Webman `-9` corresponds to `SIGKILL - terminate immediately/hard kill`: see [List of Kill Signals](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/317492/16704) and [What is the purpose of the -9 option in the kill command?](https://askubuntu.com/q/184071/44876))

Comment: `lsof -t -i:8080 | xargs -r kill` handles the empty list case better.

Comment: I needed `sudo kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:80)`

Comment: how to prevent it from restart ? After hard kill process restarts again.                                                                       tcp6     0      0 :::9100    :::*      LISTEN      57131/node_exporter

Comment: There is a TOCTOU issue with using lsof and kill, depending on what you're doing (not an issue in the case of an SSH tunnel you picked the port for and only one instance of your script is running). I'm not sure if fuser avoids it - it may be platform dependent.

Comment: the middle `kill $(lsof -t -i:8080)` worked for me, Thanks! (MBP M1Pro)

Answer (score 364):

**Option 1** A One-liner to kill only LISTEN on specific port:

```
kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:3000 -sTCP:LISTEN)
```

---

**Option 2** If you have npm installed you can also run

```
npx kill-port 3000
```

Comment: Based on this answer I created a function into `~/.bashrc`: `killp() { kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:"$1" -sTCP:LISTEN) }` in order to be able to use it like this `killp 3000`. (Do not forget to add new lines for `{ }`)

Comment: Nit: syntax error for the extra **`**

Comment: possible TOCTOU issue depending on the use case

Answer (score 256):

One liner, a time saver

```
kill -9 $(lsof -t -i tcp:8080)
```

Explanation here: use a combination of `lsof` and `kill`

```
root@localhost:~# lsof -i tcp:8080
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    23672 sine  238u  IPv6 3028222      0t0  TCP localhost:http-alt (LISTEN)
```

select pid and use `kill`

```
kill 23672
```

Answer (score 149):

You can use the lsof command.
Let port number like here is 8090

```
lsof -i:8090
```

This command returns a list of open processes on this port.

Something like…

```
COMMAND PID USER FD TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ssh 75782 eoin 5u IPv6 0x01c1c234 0t0 TCP localhost:8090 (LISTEN)
```

To free the port, kill the process using it(the process id is 75782)…

```
kill -9 75782
```

This one worked for me.
here is the link from the original post: [link](http://magp.ie/2011/04/19/find-process-using-port-number-in-bash/)

Comment: to kill process forcefully you will need to use -9
like kill -9 75782; as sometimes few processes aren't kill with just kill

Answer (score 97):

If you want to kill a process running on port number 8080 then first you need to find the 8080 port process identification number(PID) and then kill it. Run the following command to find 8080 port number PID:

```
sudo lsof -t -i:8080
```

Here,

- **sudo** - command to ask admin privilege(user id and password).
- **lsof** - list of files(Also used for to list related processes)
- **-t** - show only process ID
- **-i** - show only internet connections related process
- **:8080** - show only processes in this port number

So you can now easily kill your PID using following command:

```
sudo kill -9 <PID>
```

Here,

- kill - command to kill the process
- -9 - forcefully

You can use one command to to kill a process on a specific port using the following command:

```
sudo kill -9 $(sudo lsof -t -i:8080)
```

For more you can see the following link
[How to kill a process on a specific port on linux](https://mr-khan.gitlab.io/linux/2018/05/02/kill-specific-port-on-linux.html)

Comment: thanks mate. `sudo kill -9 $(sudo lsof -t -i:8080)` worked for me

Comment: Awesome, this is the command that worked for me, `Ubuntu`

Answer (score 83):

Best way to kill all processes on a specific port;

```
kill -9 $(sudo lsof -t -i:8080)
```

Comment: doesn't sudo prompt for password

Comment: kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]. It seems to -l is missing as recommended  `kill -l -9 $(sudo lsof -t -i:8983)`

Answer (score 51):

This prints to stdout the process ids of everything running on `<port_number>`:

```
fuser -n tcp <port_number>
```

It also prints some stuff to stderr, so:

```
fuser -n tcp <port_number> 2> /dev/null
```

We can then supply these process ids to the `kill` command:

```
sudo kill $(fuser -n tcp <port_number> 2> /dev/null)
```

You could also put this in a function if you do it a lot:

```
function killport() {
    sudo kill $(fuser -n tcp $1 2> /dev/null)
}
```

Answer (score 45):

**To know the pid of service running on particular port :**

```
netstat -tulnap | grep :*port_num*
```

you will get the description of that process. Now use kill or kill -9 pid. Easily killed.

e.g

`netstat -ap | grep :8080`

```
tcp6       0      0 :::8080       :::*    LISTEN      1880/java
```

Now:

```
kill -9 1880
```

Remember to run all commands as `root`

Answer (score 42):

Get the PID of the task and kill it.

```
lsof -ti:8080 | xargs kill
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Very smoothly works in Mac OS. You are the best. Just Up Vote.

Comment: Works well with port ranges, too, like `lsof -ti:8080-8089 | xargs kill`.

Answer (score 36):

First you need to do is run (replace with your port number):

```
fuser -k 3000/tcp
```

This will release the port. After you run the above command run:

```
service docker restart
```

And your problem is resolved.

Comment: good answer thanks it also work for me too

Comment: Thanks guys, appreciated 

Answer (score 29):

try like this,

```
 sudo fuser -n tcp -k 8080
```

Answer (score 25):

This will kill programs running on port 80

```
sudo fuser -k 80/tcp
```

Comment: correct but redundant - identical to an above answer

Answer (score 23):

Choose the port number and apply the grep in **netstat** command as shown below

```
netstat -ap | grep :7070
```

Console Output

> tcp       0      0 :::7070       :::*    LISTEN      3332/java

Kill the **service** based on **PID** ( Process Identification Number )

```
kill -9 3332
```

Answer (score 19):

Run the following command to find 8080 port number PID:

> sudo lsof -t -i:8080

You can now easily kill your PID using following command:

> sudo kill -9

You can use one command to to kill a process on a specific port using the following command:

> sudo kill -9 $(sudo lsof -t -i:8000)

Answer (score 16):

You can know **list of all ports running** in system along with its details (pid, address etc.) :

```
netstat -tulpn
```

You can know **details of a particular port number** by providing port number in following command :

```
sudo netstat -lutnp | grep -w '{port_number}'
```

ex:  sudo netstat -lutnp | grep -w '8080'
Details will be provided like this :

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
```

**if you want to kill a process using pid then** : `kill -9 {PID}`

**if you want to kill a process using port number** : `fuser -n tcp {port_number}`

use `sudo` if you are not able to access any.

Answer (score 15):

1. `lsof -i tcp:8000`
   This command lists the information about process running in port 8000
2. `kill -9 [PID]`
   This command kills the process

Comment: I just noticed that I downvoted this by accident a few weeks ago, if you edit your anwer slightly I should be able to remove it

Answer (score 15):

**Linux**: First you can find PID of this command if you know the port :

```
netstat -tulpn
```

example:-

```
 Local Address  Foreign Address  State    PID/Program name

  :::3000       :::*             LISTEN    15986/node
```

You then take the kill process. run the following command:

kill -9 PID

Expample: -

kill -9 15986

Answer (score 14):

**Linux**: You can use this command if you know the port :

```
netstat -plten | grep LISTEN | grep 8080
```

**AIX**:

```
netstat -Aan | grep LISTEN | grep 8080
```

You then take the first column (example: f100050000b05bb8) and run the following command:

```
rmsock f100050000b05bb8 tcpcb
```

kill process.

Answer (score 10):

Simply run this command. Don't forget to replace `portnumber`, with your port ;)

```
  kill -9 $(sudo lsof -t -i:portnumber)
```

Comment: No need sudo in mac most of the time.

Answer (score 7):

`` kill -9 `fuser 8080/tcp|xargs -n 1` ``, this commands also kills the process that listens on port 8080 with TCP connection

Answer (score 6):

```
sudo apt-get install psmisc (or sudo yum install psmisc)
sudo fuser 80/tcp
```

Result:
   80/tcp:       1858  1867  1868  1869  1871

Kill process one by one

kill -9 1858

Answer (score 6):

This is the solution for Windows:

```
C:\Users\Niroshan>netstat -ano|findstr "PID :8080"

Proto Local Address Foreign Address State PID
TCP 0.0.0.0:8080 0.0.0.0:0 LISTENING 18264

taskkill /pid 18264 /f
```

Comment: The question asks about Linux.

Answer (score 5):

I'm working on a Yocto Linux system that has a limited set of available Linux tools. I wanted to kill the process that was using a particular port (1883).

First, to see what ports we are listening to I used the following command:

```sh
root@root:~# netstat -lt
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:hostmon         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 localhost.localdomain:domain 0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1883            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::hostmon              :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 localhost:domain        :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::ssh                  :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::1883                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

Next, I found the name of the process using port 1883 in the following way:

```sh
root@root:~# fuser 1883/tcp
290 
root@root:~# ps | grep 290
  290 mosquitt 25508 S    /usr/sbin/mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf
12141 root      8444 S    grep 290
```

As we can see above, it's the program `/usr/sbin/mosquitto` that's using port 1883.

Lastly, I killed the process:

```sh
root@root:~# systemctl stop mosquitto
```

I used `systemctl` becuase in this case it was a systemd service.

Answer (score 4):

1. first check the process `netstat -lt`
2. check process id `fuser <port number>/tcp`
3. kill the process running on the port `kill <process id>`

Answer (score 3):

Other way with Git Bash:

```
stopProcessByPortNumber() {
port=":${1}"
portStrLine="$(netstat -ano | findstr LISTENING | findstr $port)"
processId="$(grep -oP '(\d+)(?!.*\d)' <<< $portStrLine)"
echo $processId
taskkill -PID $processId -F
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case cent os has some issue in suggested answer. So I used following solution :

```
  ss -tanp | grep 65432 | head -1 | grep -Po "(?<=pid=).*(?=,)" | xargs kill
```

Answer (score 3):

Just this commands work for me:

```
ps -aux | grep 8000
```

and then:

```
sudo kill <PID>
```

Comment: ps -aux including following headers, and port is not one of them:
USER         PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND

Answer (score 3):

My personal way to solve this issue [can be found is this gist I made](https://gist.github.com/AngusC222/307f5fef232bcf67438dbdad5ac9c060), in the gist the first step is to run:

```
sudo lsof -i [PROTOCAL]:[PORT]
```

And then run:

```
sudo kill -9 [PROCESS ID]
```

Answer (score 2):

to build on what @[veer7](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1356127/veer7) said:

if you want to know what was on the port, do this before you kill it.

```
$ sudo netstat -plten |grep java
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          :::*                    LISTEN      1000       906726      25296/java      
tcp6       0      0 :::8009                 :::*                    LISTEN      1000       907503      25296/java      
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      1000       907499      25296/java      
$ ps 25296
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
25296 ?        Sl     0:16 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Dcatalina.base=/hom
```

Use 'ps' and the number of the process that netstat reported back

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me in mac

```
sudo kill -9 $(netstat -vnap tcp | grep PORT | awk -F " " '{print $9}')
```

Answer (score 1):

How to kill process if the service on the port is not responding

```
timeout 1 telnet localhost 8080 2>&1 | if grep -q 'Unable'; then sudo kill -9 $(sudo lsof -t -i:8080); fi
```

What it does

1. Start 'timeout' with one second, to make telnet exit
2. ' 2>&1 | ' pipe error-message without exiting
3. If error-message contains 'Unable', then run the kode to kill process locking port 8080

This can ble placed in a file and run regulary from 'sudo crontab'

Answer (score 1):

Using this script, which is more user-friendly than other options and checks that the port is actually in use.

Usage: `openport 1234`

```
openport() {
  # sed = second line https://stackoverflow.com/a/1429628/152711
  # awk = second word https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/174038
  processId=$(lsof -i tcp:$1 | sed -n 2p | awk '{print $2}')
  if [ ! -z "$processId" ] # Non-null https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-shell-find-out-if-a-variable-has-null-value-or-not/
  then
    echo Killing $processId
    kill -9 $processId
  else
    echo No process found
  fi
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In Windows, it will be `netstat -ano | grep "8080"` and we get the following message `TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       10076`

WE can kill the PID using  `taskkill /F /PID 10076`

Comment: The question is clearly asking for Linux help; not Windows.