# How to stop flask application without using ctrl-c

Tags: python, flask

I want to implement a command which can stop flask application by using flask-script.
I have searched the solution for a while. Because the framework doesn't provide `app.stop()` API, I am curious about how to code this. I am working on Ubuntu 12.10 and Python 2.7.3.

Comment: Why do you need to be able to stop your application from a script?  (The best tool for the job will depend on what you are trying to do).

Comment: Seriously, what are you trying to do here? If you are talking about devserver for development, it is perfectly fine to stop it like that. In production you don't deploy like this and you can stop a request at any time you want, so the "app stops running".

Comment: @SeanVieira I want to know if there any solutions to do this.

Comment: @IgnasB. I am developing a RESTful service on my machine right now. I am working on a project maybe it will help me to choose which machines should I deploy.The only way I can figure out is shutdown by killing the process.

Comment: @vrootic, but you will not use app.run() in production anyway. app.run() is used only for development and to test your application while developing. There are different ways how to run Flask in production, more can be found here for example http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#deploying-to-a-web-server And if you deploy somehow like that already (so I misunderstood question), the way to stop serving request coming to Flask is to stop http server which is serving it.

Comment: If you want to programmatically stop the server, you could kill the server using shell commands like ps, grep and kill.  Then you can call the script from python using the os.system function to execute the shell commands.

Comment: I rarely get worked up about OSS. It's free so take it or shut up. But what is wrong with Flask? `func = request.environ.get('werkzeug.server.shutdown')` just to shutdown the server? Seriously? And the other answers are even more disconcerting. This feels like having to get under the hood of your car and throw a wrench into the cylinders just to stop the engine.

Comment: The question that I asked here is more than 10 yrs. I was in an internship and developed some internal tools. Judging from the Python & OS version, you all know that it's a very outdated question. Obviously, this approach wouldn't need to run on production server. Flask is good. It provides some useful tools at least for me when I was young. I think I got lucky to receive so many answers here. The question itself may not be that important anymore, but the discussion worths being kept here for future reference.

Answer (score 202, accepted):

If you are just running the server on your desktop, you can expose an endpoint to kill the server (read more at [Shutdown The Simple Server](http://web.archive.org/web/20190706125149/http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/67)):

```
from flask import request
def shutdown_server():
    func = request.environ.get('werkzeug.server.shutdown')
    if func is None:
        raise RuntimeError('Not running with the Werkzeug Server')
    func()
    
@app.get('/shutdown')
def shutdown():
    shutdown_server()
    return 'Server shutting down...'
```

Here is another approach that is more contained:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

server = Process(target=app.run)
server.start()
# ...
server.terminate()
server.join()
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Do you know if there's any way to get the 'werkzeug.server.shutdown' property without needing a request context?

Comment: I had to change route method to 'GET' to get it to work.

Comment: For completeness this answer is missing the function you would call outside of a request context to do the shutdown, which would be nothing more than a HTTP request to the server (which can originate from/to localhost)

Comment: When I do this multiprocessing method the server fails to join back. Can anybody help?

Comment: With `methods='POST'`, I get a `405 Method not allowed` error, whereas with methods='GET'`, it works as @CS suggested.

Comment: Did not work for me on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Worked well locally

Comment: Anybody else just get here from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36465899/how-to-run-flask-server-in-the-background ?

Comment: Running flask as a `Process` doesn't work for me on Windows (pickling error since Windows can't `fork`), was your example run on Linux/MacOS?

Comment: Does it affect other apps running on the python apps on the system? My thoughts are aligned towards thinking that WSGI serves all the apps running on the system, so shutting it down will make the other apps hosted on the same machine unavailable.

Comment: btw, the first method has been deprecated now: https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/pull/1873

Comment: I am getting following error message `AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'environ'`

Comment: The multiprocessing approach worked brilliantly for me. I needed to stop a flask server in response to a command (for testing). The stop command sets a multiprocessing.Event(); the main code polls for it to be set, terminating the process when it is.

Comment: Doesn't work on Flask 3.0.0 Windows and Docker (Ubuntu) environments as `request.environ.get('werkzeug.server.shutdown')` returns None. But `os.kill(pid, 9)` is working well if Flask app run in a separate process.

Answer (score 79):

I did it slightly different using threads

```
from werkzeug.serving import make_server

class ServerThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, app):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.server = make_server('127.0.0.1', 5000, app)
        self.ctx = app.app_context()
        self.ctx.push()

    def run(self):
        log.info('starting server')
        self.server.serve_forever()

    def shutdown(self):
        self.server.shutdown()

def start_server():
    global server
    app = flask.Flask('myapp')
    # App routes defined here
    server = ServerThread(app)
    server.start()
    log.info('server started')

def stop_server():
    global server
    server.shutdown()
```

I use it to do end to end tests for restful api, where I can send requests using the python requests library.

Comment: I did not manage to get the other stuff to work but this solution works great! Thanks a ton! For the other people: it also works with flask restful!

Comment: This seems to block on windows until I hit it with another request... any way around that?

Comment: I'm having the same issue as @Claudiu, except on Linux with python 3.6.2

Comment: I don't know why this isn't accepted, but it seems to be the cleanest and works great without any extra dependencies. Thanks so much.

Comment: In this case where do you put the endpoints?

Comment: The endpoints can go inside the start_server() method after the app is instantiated, before the ServerThread(app)

Comment: The accepted answer didn't work for me. This one does. +1.

Answer (score 40):

This is a bit old thread, but if someone experimenting, learning, or testing basic flask app, started from a script that runs in the background, the quickest way to stop it is to kill the process running on the port you are running your app on.
Note: I am aware the author is looking for a way not to kill or stop the app. But this may help someone who is learning.

```
sudo netstat -tulnp | grep :5001
```

You'll get something like this.

> tcp     0     0 0.0.0.0:5001     0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN    28834/python

To stop the app, kill the process

```
sudo kill 28834
```

Comment: I had to use ```sudo kill -9 28834``` before the process could be killed.

Answer (score 21):

My method can be proceeded via bash terminal/console

1) run and get the process number

```
$ ps aux | grep yourAppKeywords
```

2a) kill the process

```
$ kill processNum
```

2b) kill the process if above not working

```
$ kill -9 processNum
```

Comment: I am nearly sure that the question is not "how to kill a process", and the problem is that doing ctrl+c doesn't kill it. Btw, i do use `kill -9 \`lsof -i:5000 -t\`` cuz no other than just 1 app can use the port and is being easy.

Comment: Yeah I always do this

Answer (score 16):

You don't have to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, but you can provide an endpoint which does it for you:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
import json, os, signal

@app.route('/stopServer', methods=['GET'])
def stopServer():
    os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGINT)
    return jsonify({ "success": True, "message": "Server is shutting down..." })
```

Now you can just call this endpoint to gracefully shutdown the server:

```
curl localhost:5000/stopServer
```

Comment: I tested your code, but after `os.kill`, the returned response cannot be received by the client. For `curl`, it outputs "curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection was reset". May see also [Execute a function after Flask returns response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48994440/execute-a-function-after-flask-returns-response) to solve it.

Comment: @samm, the conclusion from that question is that is not possible unless you start a different thread, right? Then how do you shut down the flask server from that different thread?

Comment: Would an endpoint to shutdown the app not potentially cause a security risk with respect to availability?

Comment: I am using this code as the server.shutdown is deprecated. 
Before I do that, is this code okay to run in a production scenario?

Comment: The `os.kill` immediately stops the server so it'll never send the response. But should it? If it sent the response after hitting the API, it actually hasn't killed the server. Are you going to hit it again just to make sure it is down or shouldn't you expect a 404 immediately?

Answer (score 14):

As others have pointed out, you can only use `werkzeug.server.shutdown` from a request handler. The only way I've found to shut down the server at another time is to send a request to yourself. For example, the `/kill` handler in this snippet will kill the dev server unless another request comes in during the next second:

```py
import requests
from threading import Timer
from flask import request
import time

LAST_REQUEST_MS = 0
@app.before_request
def update_last_request_ms():
    global LAST_REQUEST_MS
    LAST_REQUEST_MS = time.time() * 1000


@app.post('/seriouslykill')
def seriouslykill():
    func = request.environ.get('werkzeug.server.shutdown')
    if func is None:
        raise RuntimeError('Not running with the Werkzeug Server')
    func()
    return "Shutting down..."


@app.post('/kill')
def kill():
    last_ms = LAST_REQUEST_MS
    def shutdown():
        if LAST_REQUEST_MS <= last_ms:  # subsequent requests abort shutdown
            requests.post('http://localhost:5000/seriouslykill')
        else:
            pass

    Timer(1.0, shutdown).start()  # wait 1 second
    return "Shutting down..."
```

Comment: this works but feels... _very_ hacky. I know it's been a while, but did you ever find a clean way of doing this, without sending a request to yourself?

Answer (score 14):

This is an old question, but googling didn't give me any insight in how to accomplish this.

Because I didn't read the [code here](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/67/) properly! (Doh!)
What it does is to raise a `RuntimeError` when there is no `werkzeug.server.shutdown` in the `request.environ`...

So what we can do when there is no `request` is to raise a `RuntimeError`

```
def shutdown():
    raise RuntimeError("Server going down")
```

and catch that when `app.run()` returns:

```
...
try:
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0")
except RuntimeError, msg:
    if str(msg) == "Server going down":
        pass # or whatever you want to do when the server goes down
    else:
        # appropriate handling/logging of other runtime errors
# and so on
...
```

No need to send yourself a request.

Answer (score 10):

If you're working on the CLI and only have one flask app/process running (or rather, you just want want to kill *any* flask process running on your system), you can kill it with:

`kill $(pgrep -f flask)`

Answer (score 7):

If you're outside the request-response handling, you can still:

```
import os
import signal

sig = getattr(signal, "SIGKILL", signal.SIGTERM)
os.kill(os.getpid(), sig)
```

Comment: Nice one, thanks. I needed to add some cleanup code before terminating on Ctrl+C, so I created a SIGINT handler, which does the job and then calls your code.

Comment: my flaskapp is funny, even sigkill doesn't work

Answer (score 7):

`request.environ.get` [deprecated](https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy/issues/628#issuecomment-848237040).
[Pavel Minaev](https://github.com/int19h) solution is pretty clear:

```py
import os
from flask import Flask


app = Flask(__name__)
exiting = False

@app.route("/exit")
def exit_app():
    global exiting
    exiting = True
    return "Done"

@app.teardown_request
def teardown(exception):
    if exiting:
        os._exit(0)
```

Comment: a) explanation would be cool 
b) this does not send the "Done" back to the caller

Answer (score 3):

If someone else is looking how to stop Flask server inside **win32 service** - here it is. It's kinda weird combination of several approaches, but it works well. Key ideas:

1. These is `shutdown` endpoint which can be used for graceful shutdown. *Note*: it relies on `request.environ.get` which is usable **only** inside web request's context (inside `@app.route`-ed function)
2. win32service's `SvcStop` method uses `requests` to do HTTP request to the service itself.

**myservice_svc.py**

```
import win32service
import win32serviceutil
import win32event
import servicemanager
import time
import traceback
import os

import myservice


class MyServiceSvc(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "MyServiceSvc"                       # NET START/STOP the service by the following name
    _svc_display_name_ = "Display name"  # this text shows up as the service name in the SCM
    _svc_description_ = "Description" # this text shows up as the description in the SCM

    def __init__(self, args):
        os.chdir(os.path.dirname(myservice.__file__))
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        # ... some code skipped
        myservice.start()

    def SvcStop(self):
        """Called when we're being shut down"""
        myservice.stop()
        # tell the SCM we're shutting down
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
                              servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STOPPED,
                              (self._svc_name_, ''))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.chdir(os.path.dirname(myservice.__file__))
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(MyServiceSvc)
```

**myservice.py**

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

# Workaround - otherwise doesn't work in windows service.
cli = sys.modules['flask.cli']
cli.show_server_banner = lambda *x: None

app = Flask('MyService')

# ... business logic endpoints are skipped.

@app.route("/shutdown", methods=['GET'])
def shutdown():
    shutdown_func = request.environ.get('werkzeug.server.shutdown')
    if shutdown_func is None:
        raise RuntimeError('Not running werkzeug')
    shutdown_func()
    return "Shutting down..."


def start():
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', threaded=True, port=5001)


def stop():
    import requests
    resp = requests.get('http://0.0.0.0:5001/shutdown')
```

Answer (score 3):

I found that killing the own PID seems to work, like follows:

```py
import os
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
own_pid = os.getpid() # Get the main process's PID in a global variable

@app.route('/kill-backend')
def kill_backend():
    global own_pid # Make sure to use the global variable
    os.kill(own_pid, 9) # The second argument is the signal, 9 stands for SIGKILL.
#If you want to "politely ask" the server to quit you can use SIGTERM (3) or SIGQUIT (15) instead.

app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```

I have tested this on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and on Window$ 10. It works on both.

To trigger the server kill, just request `http://localhost:8000/kill-backend` and it'll fail with a `connection refused` error because the server is immediately dead.

Comment: Why do you use a global variable?

Comment: @WolfgangKuehn I use a global variable to avoid getting the request handler's PID, if I kill that only the one request will fail but the server will keep running, as it starts a process for each request. With the global variable containing the main process's PID I make sure to kill the main process.

Answer (score 2):

If the port is known (e.g., 5000) a simple solution I have found is to enter:

```
fuser -k 5000/tcp
```

this will kill the process on port 5000.

[How to kill a process running on particular port in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583562/how-to-kill-a-process-running-on-particular-port-in-linux)

Answer (score 1):

### A Python solution

Run with:  `python kill_server.py`.

This is for **Windows only**.  Kills the servers with taskkill, by PID, gathered with netstat.

```
# kill_server.py

import os
import subprocess
import re

port = 5000
host = '127.0.0.1'
cmd_newlines = r'\r\n'

host_port = host + ':' + str(port)
pid_regex = re.compile(r'[0-9]+$')

netstat = subprocess.run(['netstat', '-n', '-a', '-o'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)  
# Doesn't return correct PID info without precisely these flags
netstat = str(netstat)
lines = netstat.split(cmd_newlines)

for line in lines:
    if host_port in line:
        pid = pid_regex.findall(line)
        if pid:
            pid = pid[0]
            os.system('taskkill /F /PID ' + str(pid))
        
# And finally delete the .pyc cache
os.system('del /S *.pyc')
```

If you are having trouble with favicon / changes to index.html loading (i.e. old versions are cached), then **try "Clear Browsing Data > Images & Files" in Chrome** as well.

Doing all the above, and I got my favicon to finally load upon running my Flask app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use method bellow

```
app.do_teardown_appcontext()
```

Comment: This is an incorrect guess. This function does not stop the app, it is called automatically to release some context at the end of processing an individual request. https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Flask.do_teardown_appcontext

Comment: this does not work for me

Answer (score 0):

## Google Cloud VM instance + Flask App

I hosted my Flask Application on Google Cloud Platform Virtual Machine.
I started the app using `python main.py` But the problem was ctrl+c did not work to stop the server.

This command `$ sudo netstat -tulnp | grep :5000` terminates the server.

My Flask app runs on port 5000 by default.

### Note: My VM instance is running on Linux 9.

It works for this. Haven't tested for other platforms.
Feel free to update or comment if it works for other versions too.

Comment: Please note: neither netstat nor grep will stop an active process.

Answer (score 0):

```py
app = MyFlaskSubclass()

...

app.httpd = MyWSGIServerSubclass()

...
 
@app.route('/shutdown')
def app_shutdown():
    from threading import Timer
    t = Timer(5, app.httpd.shutdown)
    t.start()
    return "Server shut down"
```

Comment: Providing [additional context](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/90527) regarding why & how this answer works works and when it should be used will improve its long-term value by helping readers.

Answer (score 0):

My bash script variant (LINUX):

```
#!/bin/bash
portFind="$1"
echo "Finding process on port: $portFind"
pid=$(netstat -tulnp | grep :"$1" | awk '{print $7}' | cut -f1 -d"/")
echo "Process found: $pid"
kill -9 $pid
echo "Process $pid killed"
```

Usage example:

```
sudo bash killWebServer.sh 2223
```

Output:

```
Finding process on port: 2223
Process found: 12706
Process 12706 killed
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the werkzeug `BaseWSGIServer` instance created by `werkzeug.serving.run_simple()` (which is called by `app.run()`) is not made accessible. Yet this class does define a clean `shutdown()` method that effectively terminates the server's mainloop without any hacks.

So if we can get access to that instance, we can kill the server. One way I can think of doing that is through the garbage collector's object tracking:

```py
@app.route("/shutdown", methods=["POST"])
def shutdown():
    for obj in gc.get_objects():
        try:
            if isinstance(obj, BaseWSGIServer):
                obj.shutdown()
                return "bye"
        except:
            pass
    return "failed"
```

I found myself needing this to emulate making POST callbacks in my unit tests. With this function I can run the flask server in a thread and not worry about it staying alive while I run my other tests.

Answer (score 0):

you can try use

```
pkill python
```

pkill is a command-line utility that sends signals to the processes of a running program based on given criteria. The processes can be specified by their full or partial names, a user running the process, or other attributes.

The pkill command is a part of the procps (or procps-ng) package, which is pre-installed on nearly all Linux distributions. pkill is basicity a wrapper around the pgrep program that only prints a list of matching processes.
How to Use the pkill Command

The syntax for the pkill command is as follows:

```
pkill [OPTIONS] <PATTERN>
```

The matching  is specified using extended regular expressions.

When invoked without any option, pkill sends the 15 (TERM) signal to the PIDs of all running programs that match with the given name. For example, to gracefully stop all firefox processes, you would run:

```
pkill -15 python
```

The command returns 0 when at least one running process matches the requested name. Otherwise, the exit code is 1. This can be useful when writing shell scripts.

more info here

[pkill-command-in-linux](https://linuxize.com/post/pkill-command-in-linux/)

Answer (score -12):

For Windows, it is quite easy to stop/kill flask server -

1. Goto Task Manager
2. Find flask.exe
3. Select and End process

Comment: The power button on your computer is quite effective as well haha