# Displaying output on browser with Python + Flask

Tags: python, flask

edit: Ended up using the built-in render_template function to display output using Jinja2 markup, which proved to be a perfect solution.

Answer (score 2):

Flask is a process and will keep running forever, unless it encounters a fatal exception.

Typically, a web server process exiting would be a terrible design.

Try this for the functionality you want:
[How to stop flask application without using ctrl-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15562446/how-to-stop-flask-application-without-using-ctrl-c)

Comment: Thanks for your input, John. However, I wasn't able to grasp how I could use this in the way I want it to work. What I'm trying to build is a frontend for multiple users, and I'm not sure how I would code the shutdown function into the application so that it'd kill the process after a user gets their scraped data. Sorry if I'm missing something.  **edit: Basically, I want it to scrape, print the data on browser and then stop. For multiple users.**

Comment: Add in that shutdown_server function and call it from your process.

Comment: Added the following after the return statement, still no go.

    `requests.post('http://localhost:5000/done')

    @app.route('/done', methods=['POST'])  
    def done():  
        func = request.environ.get('werkzeug.server.shutdown')  
        if func is None:  
            raise RuntimeError('Not running with the Werkzeug Server')  
        func()`

Comment: Try installing werkzeug. pip install werkzeug

Comment: I have tried it with this snippet: http://codeshare.io/EgYKr It works, potential installation issue- which version flask are you running?

Comment: That snippet works for me too but when I integrate it into my script, it doesn't work. On the console it keeps scraping the same pages over and over again, and on the browser it just hangs on loading. I don't see the output on the browser nor does the script stop. I wonder if there is a problem in my scraper code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79811/discussion-between-john-and-leet).