# Question on automatically performing certain task

Tags: python-3.x

My intention is 
1. performing a health check and everything is working fine, but the problem is, I get this message http://0.0.0.0:8080/ (Press CTRL+C to quit), which I have to manually do control c, for the next piece of code to work

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
import urllib.request as request
import time
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
starttime=time.time()

def example_fun():
    print("hello world")

class Health (Resource):
      def get(self):
        return "UP"

api.add_resource(Health, '/health')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port = '8080')
    example_fun()
    while True: 
        example_fun()
        time.sleep(3)
```

What i expect is once app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port = '8080') is executed and it is healthy, it should continue to example_fun() and start printing the result without manually performing control + c

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15562446/how-to-stop-flask-application-without-using-ctrl-c/17053522

Comment: Hi sir, my intention is to execute example_fun() after app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port = '8080') automatically

Comment: Understood; and I believe that this link above might help

Comment: I could not understand the other example apologies