# Flask unit tests not closing port after each test

Tags: python, multithreading, unit-testing, flask, multiprocessing

I'm doing some unit testing for a flask application. A part of this includes restarting the flask application for each test. To do this, I'm creating my flask application in the `setUp()` function of my `unitest.TestCase`, so that I get the application in its fresh state for each run. Also, I'm starting the application in a separate thread so the tests can run without the flask application blocking.

Example below:

```py
import requests
import unittest
from threading import Thread

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        test_port = 8000
        self.test_url = f"http://0.0.0.0:{str(test_port)}"
        self.app_thread = Thread(target=app.run, kwargs={"host": "0.0.0.0", "port": test_port, "debug": False})
        self.app_thread.start()

    def test_a_test_that_contacts_the_server(self):
        response = requests.post(
            f"{self.test_url}/dosomething",
            json={"foo": "bar"},
            headers=foo_bar
        )
        is_successful = json.loads(response.text)["isSuccessful"]
        self.assertTrue(is_successful, msg=json.loads(response.text)["message"])

    def tearDown(self):
        # what should I do here???
        pass
```

This becomes problematic because when the tests that come after the initial test run, they run into an issue with port `8000` being used. This raises `OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use`.

(For now, I've built a workaround, where I generate a list of high ranged ports, and another list of ports used per test, so that I never select a port used by a previous test. This work around works, but I'd really like to know the proper way to shut down this flask application, ultimately closing the connection and releasing/freeing that port.)

I'm hopeful that there is a specific way to shutdown this flask application in the `tearDown()` function.

**How should I go about shutting down the flask application in my `tearDown()` method?**

Comment: You don't strictly need to actually _start_ the Flask server for integration test when you can use the `app.test_client()` feature - this means you will also be able to avoid requiring a complete http client library to test the data - see [Testing Flask Applications](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/testing/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution to my own question while writing it, and since [it's encouraged to answer your own question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), I'd like to still share this for anyone else with the same issue.

**The solution to this problem is to treat the flask application as another *process* instead of a thread. This is accomplished using `Process` from the `multiprocessing` module en lieu of `Thread` from the `threading` module.**

I came to this conclusion after reading [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17053522/3589609) regarding stopping flask without using CTRL + C. Reading that answer then lead me to read about the differences between `multiprocessing` and `threading` [in this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3044626/3589609). Of course, after that, I moved on to the official documentation on the `multiprocessing` module, [found here](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing). More specifically, [this link will take you straight to the `Process` class.](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#process-and-exceptions)

I'm not able to fully articulate *why* the `multiprocessing` module serves this purpose better than `threading`, but I do feel that it makes more sense for this application. After all, the flask application is acting as its own API server that is separate from my test, and my test is testing the calls to it/responses it gets back. For this reason, I think it makes the most sense for my flask application to be its own process.

## tl;dr

Use `multiprocessing.Process` en lieu of `threading.Thread`, and then call `Process.terminate()` to kill the process, followed by `Process.join()` to block until the process is terminated.

example:

```py
import requests
import unittest
from multiprocessing import Process

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        test_port = 8000
        self.test_url = f"http://0.0.0.0:{str(test_port)}"
        self.app_process = Process(target=app.run, kwargs={"host": "0.0.0.0", "port": test_port, "debug": False})
        self.app_process.start()

    def test_a_test_that_contacts_the_server(self):
        response = requests.post(
            f"{self.test_url}/dosomething",
            json={"foo": "bar"},
            headers=foo_bar
        )
        is_successful = json.loads(response.text)["isSuccessful"]
        self.assertTrue(is_successful, msg=json.loads(response.text)["message"])

    def tearDown(self):
        self.app_process.terminate()
        self.app_process.join()
```

*Test early, and test often!*