# Running Flask API without CMD

Tags: python, flask, tkinter

I'm working on a company that deploy their system on local computer and servers.

The task given to me is to create a python application which communicates with a plc and display gathered data using `Reactjs/Electron.js` or save the data on `MS SQL Server`.

My idea was to create gui using `tkinter` and convert it to an app by creating a `<filename>.spec` file and `pyinstaller` that look like `XAMPP` where I could restart and start the api.

If I use `tkinter` where should I start? I manage to start the backend when the gui opened but I have no clue to stop or restart the backend. I also don't have much idea on `threads` but I think it would help me create what I want.

I was also searching if I could use `XAMPP` as a host to run the api but no luck.

If you guys have a better way to run the api on localhost without the cmd would really help

Comment: I don't think that running the server on another `thread` would suffice, I would suggest using another process if possible since servers are pretty resource consuming (at least I imagine so) so making it run in the same thread as tkinter may very much slow things down (this is doable if flask is pickleable, EDIT: actually that may not be needed), what I could imagine is running a `subprocess.Popen` process which will launch the server and then stream output to a text widget in tkinter, haven't yet thought about stopping but that shouldn't be too hard either (will try to write an answer)

Comment: I'll try to study `subprocess`. Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so this took a while but I figured out how to not use `subprocess` (mainly because there was another question regarding not using `python` so the only way would be to convert flask app to `.exe` and then use `subprocess` but I found out how to do this using just python), the main issue (simple fix but has to be resolved when using `subprocess.Popen` too) is that flask restarts the server which starts another process so you have to use `use_reloader=False` in `.run()` method. Explanation in comments:

**app.py**

```py
# import what's necessary
from flask import Flask, render_template_string, url_for
from flask import request


app = Flask(__name__)


# sample route
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template_string('<a href="{{ url_for("about") }}">To About Page</a>'
                                  '<h1>Home Page</h1>')


# sample route
@app.route('/about')
def about():
    return render_template_string('<a href="{{ url_for("home") }}">To Home Page</a>'
                                  '<h1>About Page</h1>')


# important route that will do the stopping part since that was a requirement in the question
# link to this in the answer at the bottom
@app.route('/kill_server', methods=['GET'])
def kill_server():
    func = request.environ.get('werkzeug.server.shutdown')
    if func is None:
        raise RuntimeError('Not running with the Werkzeug Server. Could not shut down server.')
    func()
    return 'Server shutting down...'


# to prevent this from running when importing
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**run.py**

```py
# import all that is necessary
from tkinter import Tk, Text, Button, Frame
from for_so_dir.app import app as server
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue, Empty
import requests
import logging.handlers


# simple dictionary to avoid using `global`, just a preference of mine
info = {'server_is_running': False}


# the function that starts server (multiprocessing is not possible with flask as far as I know)
# basically checks if the server is not running already and if it is not then starts a thread
# with the server (which is the same as `app` in the app.py) and sets that server is running
def start_server():
    if info['server_is_running']:
        return
    Thread(target=server.run, kwargs={'debug': True, 'use_reloader': False}, daemon=True).start()
    info['server_is_running'] = True


# function from stopping server, again in the answer at the bottom, but basically
# this sends a request to the server and that request executes a function
# that stops the server
def stop_server():
    if not info['server_is_running']:
        return
    requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/kill_server')


# function for showing the logs in the Text widget, it simply tries to get data from
# the queue (if there is nothing it simply loops again) and then inserts that data into
# the text widget
def update_text_log():
    try:
        data = queue.get(block=False)
    except Empty:
        pass
    else:
        log.config(state='normal')
        log.insert('end', data.msg + '\n')
        log.config(state='disabled')
    finally:
        root.after(100, update_text_log)


# this `if statement` is not that necessary in the current code but it might as well
# stay here
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # initialise the Queue
    queue = Queue()
    # now the main part, to get the info from flask you need to use `logging`
    # since that is what it uses for all the messages, and use the `QueueHandler`
    # to put the messages in the queue and then update them using the above
    # function
    logging.basicConfig(handlers=(logging.handlers.QueueHandler(queue), ))
    
    # simple `tkinter` stuff
    root = Tk()
    # this part can be removed or made toggleable but it allows to easier see how
    # this works in action
    root.attributes('-topmost', True)

    log = Text(root, state='disabled')
    log.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

    update_text_log()

    button_frame = Frame(root)
    button_frame.pack(fill='x')
    Button(button_frame, text='Start Server', command=start_server).pack(expand=True, fill='x', side='left')
    Button(button_frame, text='Stop Server', command=stop_server).pack(expand=True, fill='x', side='right')

    root.mainloop()
```

Sources:

- [Shutdown server (read other answers too, my code uses a simplified version of this)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26788325/14531062)
- [Logging docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html)

The only issue is about displaying the starting message in console, there is a way to remove it by adding `import os` and then `os.environ['WERKZEUG_RUN_MAIN'] = 'true'` to the `app.py` file but there is a slight issue then that stopping the server using the button will do this: `Process finished with exit code 15` (at least on Windows) so you will have to find a way to workaround this since I am not able yet to do so

Comment: And I just noticed that you also asked the other question, that I have mentioned in my answer, if you still need the option with subprocess (that requires python to be installed) I can try writing that one too, otherwise you could convert the app to exe and then run it using subprocess