# Flask Web server App on Window Python program is not able to shutdown on program exist

Tags: python, multithreading, flask

I have python version 3.9, I am using the default development web server that is provided by the flask on windows OS (laptop). I need to run the app on Windows machine, and it should be able to start and stop the app on demand.

Here is what I tried so far. when I run the application either in VS code, I need to force stop the app, If running in the command windows I have to kill the python app from task manager.
With the following code changes I can exit the app by sending the SIGTERM to proess itself, as both the Flask, and simplehttpserver do not provide an API for exiting the process.

```
from flask import Flask, request, g, make_response
import queue
import time
import os
from threading import Thread
import signal
import ctypes

from multiprocessing import Process

import sys

OUTPUT_EMPTY_LIMIT = 3 
DEFAULT_PORT = 9090

SHUTDOWN    = False
EXIT_CHARS  = "Qq\x11\x18"      # 'Q', 'q', Ctrl-Q, ESC


print("Name = {}".format(__name__))

app = Flask(__name__)


def shutdown_app():
    global SHUTDOWN
    SHUTDOWN = True

@app.before_request
def before_request():
    if SHUTDOWN:
        return 'Shutting down...'
    
def run_app(port, host, debug, threaded):
    app.run(port=port, host=host, debug=debug, threaded=threaded)

    
@app.route("/")
def app_help():
    return "Hello, World from help!"

@app.route("/square/<int:number>")
def square(number):
    return str(number**2)

# This doesnt kill the app as well.
@app.route("/stop")
def stop():
    func = request.environ.get('werkzeug.server.shutdown')
    if func is None:
        raise RuntimeError('Not running with the werkzeug Server')
    func()
    return 'Server shutting down...'
    exit(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    port = 5000
    host = '0.0.0.0'
    debug = False
    threaded = True   
    process = Process(target=run_app, args=(port, host, debug, threaded))
    process.start()
    
    while True:
        ch = input("Enter 'Q' to stop server and exit: ")
        if (ch == 'Q'):
            break
    
    shutdown_app()
    process.terminate()
    #process.kill()
    #process.join()
    print("Exiting the app")
    # os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGINT)
    os._exit(0)
```

I am new to Python and have tried both google search and chatGPT to find a way to shutdown Flask App and the web server that is started on a windows operating system.
I have also tried the other answeres on the stack overflow [15562446](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15562446/how-to-stop-flask-application-without-using-ctrl-c)

I also tried the link [Shutdown The Simple Server](https://web.archive.org/web/20190706125149/http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/67)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found while testing that werkzeug.server.shutdown does nothing, and it needs to be shutdown using sys.exit(0) on my windows machine.
In your code a value is returned before the exit() is run - therefore it does not shut down. One way to do what you want is using [deferred callbacks](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/deferredcallbacks/).

```
from flask import after_this_request 

@app.get('/stop')
def shutdown():
    @after_this_request
    def response_processor(response):
        @response.call_on_close
        def shutdown():
            import sys
            sys.exit("Stop API Called")
        return response
    return 'Server shutting down...',200
```

Comment: I tried this code, and it did not work as well. The python program in the command prompt continues to run, I do get the response "Server shutting down..." to the "curl localhost:5000/stop". To check if the shutdown is called I put a breakpoint and it seems to call the shutdown, but then an exception is raised. `Exception has occurred: SystemExit
Stop API Called
  File "<path>\app.py", line XX, in shutdown
    sys.exit("Stop API Called")
SystemExit: Stop API Called`

Comment: I checked the code to sys.exit(0) to bypass the exception, but the python program still continues to run, as the attached process (flask or webserver) is still running.

Comment: 1. Could you try os._exit() instead of sys.exit ?
2. Also what version of python and flask are you using?

Comment: I was using Threaded = False in my server. In your case sys.exit() might be getting called from a different thread, leading to this issue. If so, os._exit() should work.

Comment: I tried both   os._exit(0) and os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGTERM), but they both kill the subprocess. Not the main process. I also added  process.terminate() and os._exit(0) in the end of progam, and then it can exit if I enter 'Q' to quit the program.

Comment: I marked the question as answered as with the comments the program works, # This doesnt kill the app only the subprocess.
```@app.get('/stop')
def shutdown():
    @after_this_request
    def response_processor(response):
        @response.call_on_close
        def shutdown():
            import os
            os._exit(0)
        return response
        
    return 'Server shutting down...',200```

Comment: The following kills the process.                      if __name__ == "__main__":
    port = DEFAULT_PORT
    host = '0.0.0.0'
    debug = False
    threaded = True   
    process = Process(target=run_app, args=(port, host, debug, threaded))
    process.start()
    
    while True:
        ch = input("Enter 'Q' to stop server and exit: ")
        if (ch == 'Q'):
            break
    print("Exiting the app")    
    shutdown_app()
    process.terminate()
    os._exit(0)