# Python : Can't access localhost url generated by flask

Tags: python, api, flask

I am an absolute beginner to use flask

I am trying to run this code to generate an api that return hello world text
I run it on jupyter notebook

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/result')
def index():
    return 'Hello, World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug= False , host= 'localhost',port=2000)
```

The problem is when I run on any port number it runs fine the first time
I tried to stop the cell using ctrl + c but it doesn't stop so I stopped it using interput kernel button but when I run the code again on the same port number it does not work any more and give me loading page forever but when I change the port number it works fine again can some explain why does it happen

Comment: Check this answer. You could implement what is there to stop the flask app by code. You can then put this code at the beginnig of the cell with some checks, so if the app exists, stop it before running the cell again.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15562446/how-to-stop-flask-application-without-using-ctrl-c

Answer (score 0):

There is a good chance that when you switch to another instance of Flask, the previous instance is **still alive**.

As a result you cant start Flask on port X.
However when you switch to port Y - you are able to create another copy of your app.

Do.

`ps -ef grep python`

and you will see all your Flask instances

Comment: When I run the code 
it gives me  UID     PID    PPID  TTY        STIME COMMAND
                   eyad    6084       1 ?        15:52:43 /usr/bin/ps

Comment: How can I delete the flask instance that I have created

Comment: It really helps me as it gives information about Flask instances But I can't vote for it because I don't have 15 reputation

Comment: So I have posted the full answer for the problem

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to kill the port in windows 10 to be able to use it again

I use these commands in CMD run as admin

```
netstat -a -n -o | find "<your port id>"
```

this will display all details about this port and the PID of it

then I kill this pid using this command

```
taskkill /PID <your pid number>/F
```