# Stop apache on port 8080

Tags: apache, localhost

I am on a Mac running OSX 10.9.4

I am trying to run a Nesta app, it uses localhost:8080. I know that the app is not using the port since mr-sparkle has not yet installed.

But I entered the address and see that i left something is running. How can i find what that is and kill it, in plain English with minimal jargon. All i need is the command for the terminal.

I have tried

- [Kill what ever is running on port 8080](https://superuser.com/questions/609794/kill-what-ever-is-running-on-port-8080)

And various others but I cannot see the PID running on 8080.

This is what is showing at that localhost.

[image]

#### Edit 1

I ran `netstat -l -p | grep 8080` per a suggestion but got this

[image]

Comment: Since you've provided no details whatsoever about the OS you're running this on, we cannot help you.

Comment: @MarcB, how about just asking for clarification instead of downvoting?

Comment: This worked form me kill -9 &lt;PId&gt; http://stackoverflow.com/a/11583564/4751667

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you are on unix, use the `netstat` command with `-p` to retrieve the pid, pipe it in a grep of port 8080.

```
 netstat -l -p | grep 8080
```

Now that you have the process id,

```
pkill -9 id
```

**Edit :** Since you commented and specify you are on OSX, try with

```
lsof -nP -i | grep 8080
```

then kill the process using `pkill`

Comment: On OSX. I got this `netstat: option requires an argument -- p`

Comment: Seems like netstat on OSX does not display port.. try `lsof -nP -iTCP:$PORT -sTCP:LISTEN`

Comment: I got this `lsof: unacceptable port specification in: -i TCP:`

Comment: @JGallardo See my new edit. Sorry about the last one, could not test. Just tested this one on Yosemite and it works.

Comment: Still getting the same result. I think it is because of PostgreSQL. So I am looking at solutions to kill that from running.

Comment: ps -ef | grep PostgreSQL then kill the process.

Comment: On Mac OSX, `pkill` did not kill the process. But using `kill` did.