# Node.js Error: EADDRINUSE on Elastic Beanstalk host

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have the following error message with node.js:

```
events.js:72 
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event 
^ 
Error: listen EADDRINUSE 
at errnoException (net.js:904:11) 
at Server._listen2 (net.js:1042:14) 
at Server.wrappedListen2 [as _listen2] (/Users/rakutza/Documents/ParcelPuppy/PP/node_modules/newrelic/lib/instrumentation/core/net.js:16:46) 
at listen (net.js:1064:10) 
at Server.listen (net.js:1138:5) 
at EventEmitter.app.listen (/Users/rakutza/Documents/ParcelPuppy/PP/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:559:24) 
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/rakutza/Documents/ParcelPuppy/PP/app.js:109:18) 
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26) 
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10) 
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

Apparently the port number which listen() tries to bind the server to is already in use. How can I try another port or close the program using this port?

The app is working in production mode but once I deploy it on the server AWS BeanStalk crashes.

```
var slice = Array.prototype.slice;

/**
 * EventEmitter
 */

function EventEmitter() {
  if (!this._events) this._events = {};
}

EventEmitter.prototype.addListener = function(type, listener) {
  if (!this._events[type]) {
    this._events[type] = listener;
  } else if (typeof this._events[type] === 'function') {
    this._events[type] = [this._events[type], listener];
  } else {
    this._events[type].push(listener);
  }
  this._emit('newListener', [type, listener]);
};

EventEmitter.prototype.on = EventEmitter.prototype.addListener;

EventEmitter.prototype.removeListener = function(type, listener) {
  var handler = this._events[type];
  if (!handler) return;

  if (typeof handler === 'function' || handler.length === 1) {
    delete this._events[type];
    this._emit('removeListener', [type, listener]);
    return;
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < handler.length; i++) {
    if (handler[i] === listener || handler[i].listener === listener) {
      handler.splice(i, 1);
      this._emit('removeListener', [type, listener]);
      return;
    }
  }
};

EventEmitter.prototype.off = EventEmitter.prototype.removeListener;

EventEmitter.prototype.removeAllListeners = function(type) {
  if (type) {
    delete this._events[type];
  } else {
    this._events = {};
  }
};

EventEmitter.prototype.once = function(type, listener) {
  function on() {
    this.removeListener(type, on);
    return listener.apply(this, arguments);
  }
  on.listener = listener;
  return this.on(type, on);
};

EventEmitter.prototype.listeners = function(type) {
  return typeof this._events[type] === 'function'
    ? [this._events[type]]
    : this._events[type] || [];
};
```

Comment: might be of some use : [how-to-kill-process-running-on-particular-port-in-linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583562/how-to-kill-process-running-on-particular-port-in-linux)

Answer (score 4):

Nowhere in your code are you showing where you are listening on a network socket...

In any case, for Beanstalk, you should use the `PORT` environment variable, accessible via `process.env.PORT`.  If you don't, you have no guarantee of using the port that Beanstalk wants you to listen in on.

Beanstalk instances have their own Nginx proxies in front of your Node.js application.  Your app isn't accessed directly.  That's likely why you are running into a collision.

Comment: Thanks! How do I set that for EB?  This is my Express configuration: /**
 * Express configuration.
 */
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 1337);

Comment: @user3464679 You don't set it.  It's set for you by the system.

Comment: Ok. And what are my options for avoiding this problem then? And this is the code for starting my Express server : /**
 * Start Express server.
 */
var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('server listening on port %d in %s mode', app.get('port'), app.get('env'));
});

Comment: `app.listen(process.env.PORT)`

Comment: Instead of app.get('port') ?

Comment: If I change that my webapp won't load at all in production or in development mode. Webpage not available - connection refused

Comment: @user3464679 Are you running this on Beanstalk or not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77474/discussion-between-user3464679-and-brad).

Comment: I have a HAPI server and (thanks Brad) the following solved it:
server.connection({port: process.env.PORT});

Comment: Did anybody find any solution? Please post here

Comment: @Ima This is a solution.  If it's not working for you, post a new question.