# (nodemon) app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting

Tags: linux, ubuntu, npm, nodemon

I cloned this [repo](https://github.com/FarmBot/mqtt-gateway) from gitHub so, while installing in the last step I try to run this command:

`~/mqtt-gateway$ WEB_API_URL=http://localhost:3000 npm start`

And I get this error:

`[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...`

I've read that possibly is because of a process that haven't been terminated but I've been unable to solve it.

Hope you can help. Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the error output it said:

`Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::1883`

The port used for this program is 1883 and I was running mosquitto on that same port so I killed it:

`netstat -plten |grep mosquitto`

and then

`kill -9 PID`

like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583562/how-to-kill-a-process-running-on-particular-port-in-linux).

Just in case anyone faces a similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

i had that issue myself, when i was building a server .. on command npm run dev:server, it was always rejecting me with that message "[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting"

my package.json was:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev:server": "nodemon --watch build --exec node \"build/bundle.js\"",
    "dev:build:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.js --watch"
  },
```

so i just removed those escaping backslashes and everything worked fine.

```
"scripts": {
        "dev:server": "nodemon --watch build --exec node build/bundle.js",
        "dev:build:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.js --watch"
      }
```