# Stop MySql on EC2 - CentOS

Tags: mysql, docker, amazon-ec2, centos

Trying to run Docker with mysql in it but it complains:

```
Bind for 0.0.0.0:3306 failed: port is already allocated
```

How to stop everything that is running on this port?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to kill a process running on particular port in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583562/how-to-kill-a-process-running-on-particular-port-in-linux)

Answer (score 0):

Stop mysql database: `/etc/init.d/mysqld stop` and then try to run container again