# Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)

Tags: java, networking, server, client, serversocket

I initially tried to connect to port `9090` but it throws the exception. I then tried another port number `61231` and it threw the exception again. (this how i init the port)

```
ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(61231);
```

I also know what ports are available on the server.
[image: netstat on linux]

When I do `Java DataServer` in `linux` terminal

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:387)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:128)
        at DataServer.main(DataServer.java:15)
```

I am able to get the server to reply back to me
[image]

DataServer.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Date;

/*A TCP server that runs on port 9090.
When a client connects, it sends the
client the current date and time, then
closes the connection with that client.*/

public class DataServer {
    /*** Runs the server.*/
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(61231);
        try {
            while (true) {
                Socket socket = listener.accept();
                try {
                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                    out.println(new Date().toString());
                } finally {
                    socket.close();
                }
            }
        } finally {
            listener.close();
        }
    }
}
```

DataClient.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class DataClient {
    /*** Runs the client as an application.
     * First it displays
     * a dialog box asking for the IP address or hostname
     * * of a host running the date server, then connects to
     * * it and displays the date that it serves.*/
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // String serverAddress = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
        //     "Enter IP Address of a machine that is\n" +
        //     "running the date service on port 9090:");
        System.out.print("Please input the server address:");
        // Enter data using BufferReader
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        //Reading data using readLine
        String serverAddress = reader.readLine();

        Socket s = new Socket(serverAddress, 61231);
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        String answer = input.readLine();
        System.out.println("Reply" + answer);
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, answer);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: netstat -a -n -o | find "9090" try this , or change port no to 61231 to find which pid is uses this port

Comment: Some other program must be using the same port.

Comment: @Eliwa i get this when I do netstat -a -n -o | find "9090"  
"find: ‘9090’: No such file or directory"
I am using Git Bash terminal is that the problem??

Comment: try to make it using CMD .you are using linux?

Comment: yes i am using linux

Comment: sudo netstat -lutnp | grep -w '8080'

Comment: kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:8080)

Comment: possibly duplicated source : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583562/how-to-kill-a-process-running-on-particular-port-in-linux