# Hot-key to properly kill node process and freeing used port

Tags: node.js, linux, express

Hey guys I know this is a question that has been tackled few times with different flavors. I was just curious if any of you knew the magical hot-key in Ubuntu to kill a node process without facing the infamous EADDRINUSE ::XXXX issue when you restart your process. I know already there are many ways of finding the pid of the process using the port and properly killing it;

```
sudo ss -lptn 'sport = :XXXX'

kill -9 PID
```

But there must be a nicer way.

In the hope of some Linux guru may help.

Thanks

Comment: Just create a script for the commands and run that instead

Comment: I realize that my question is unpopular. I am specificaly asking for a hot-key to stop process and ensure that process using the port are totally free. Why aren't process properly cleared anyways?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use this: `kill $(lsof -t -i:portnumber)`

if you know what port the process runs on.

I found this in this answer: [How to kill a process running on particular port in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583562/how-to-kill-a-process-running-on-particular-port-in-linux) and tested it.

Comment: Yes that works but would there be a way to cleanly free the used ports once stopping node with ctrl+x or ctrl+z or ctrl+c?

Answer (score -1):

After all, if anybody face this newbie error like I had, in linux ubuntu the golden rule is that usually ctrl+c shuts down process properly and frees the used port of the process.

```
ctrl+c
```

Sorry for the bad question.