# How to connect node.js to MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to connect node.js to MySQL and failed. I have installed MySQL and relevant libraries. How do I resolve this error? Also, if I want to get data to react-native, how should I go about doing it?

```js
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql');

const connection = mysql.createPool({
  host     : '*****',//aws db endpoint/MySQL hostname
  user     : 'administrator', // username of MySQL connection
  password : '*****', //pw of MySQL db
  database : 'database_3' // name of database to be used
});

const app = express();
app.get('/User', function (req, res) {
    connection.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM User', function (error, results, fields) {
      if (error) throw error;
      res.send(results)
    });
  });
});

// Starting our server.
app.listen(3306, () => {
    console.log('Go to http://localhost:3306/User');
   });
```

The error msg received :

```js
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3306
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1279:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1327:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1414:7)
    at Function.listen (C:\Users\Irvin\my-new-project\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:618:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Irvin\my-new-project\route.js:39:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1306:8)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:834:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3306

This means that the port `3306` is already in use, try changing it to another port or stop the process running on that port.

```js
// Lets change 3306 to 3307
app.listen(3307, () => {
    console.log('Go to http://localhost:3307/User');
});
```

If you want to stop the process on this port [here is how to do it on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583562/how-to-kill-a-process-running-on-particular-port-in-linux)

Answer (score 1):

3306 is the default mysql port. Don't use that port for a server if you already have mysql running.

Don't stop the process on that port otherwise mysql will stop running, unless you're running it in another port, which is not your case.

```
app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Go to http://localhost:3306/User');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi since you are running mysql, it runs on port 3306 by default. Since you are tryung to start your express app on the same port, you get this error. You need to start your express application on any other port.

Answer (score 0):

Your `nodeJs` application is using same port with `MySQL` .

```
// Starting our server.
   app.listen(3306, () => {
    console.log('Go to http://localhost:3306/User');
   });
```

That `app.listen(3306)` is your `nodeJs` application listening port,
your current `MySQL` listening port is also `3306` ，
so your `nodeJs` application throw an error

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3306
```

Means the port `3306` is already in use .
You should change your `nodeJs` application listening port like `8080` or `8090`,
For example :

```
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql');

const connection = mysql.createPool({
  host     : '*****',//aws db endpoint/MySQL hostname
  user     : 'administrator', // username of MySQL connection
  password : '*****', //pw of MySQL db
  database : 'database_3' // name of database to be used
});

const app = express();
app.get('/User', function (req, res) {
    connection.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM User', function (error, results, fields) {
      if (error) throw error;
      res.send(results)
    });
  });
});

// change this port to 8090
app.listen(8090, () => {
    console.log('Go to http://localhost:3306/User');
   });
```