# Deno Uncaught AddrInUse: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. (os error 10048)

Tags: deno

When I try to run my deno file I got `os error 10048`, How can I solve this error? Thank you

```
 import { Application } from 'https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts'

const app = new Application();
const port = 3000;

app.use((ctx) => {
    ctx.response.body = "Hello World"
})

app.listen({ port })
console.log(`localhost:${port}`)
```

I tried to Run my Deno file but I got this error

```
D:\Deno Documentation\deno3>deno run --allow-net ./server.js
localhost:3000
error: Uncaught AddrInUse: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. (os error 10048)
    at unwrapResponse ($deno$/ops/dispatch_json.ts:43:11)
    at Object.sendSync ($deno$/ops/dispatch_json.ts:72:10)
    at Object.listen ($deno$/ops/net.ts:51:10)
    at listen ($deno$/net.ts:152:22)
    at Application.serve (https://deno.land/std@0.56.0/http/server.ts:252:20)
    at Application.listen (https://deno.land/x/oak/application.ts:295:20)
    at file:///D:/Deno%20Documentation/deno3/server.js:10:5
```

Comment: Sometime just upgrade deno can fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have another program listening on port `3000`, change the port to an unused one, or kill the program running on `3000`.

Comment: I just got it and the port seems to have changed to 8000.

Answer (score 2):

How to kill a process running on particular port :

- simple way close you browser.
- [How to kill a process running on particular port in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583562/how-to-kill-a-process-running-on-particular-port-in-linux)
- [How to kill a process running on particular port in windows?](https://medium.com/@javatechie/how-to-kill-the-process-currently-using-a-port-on-localhost-in-windows-31ccdea2a3ea)
- [Find (and kill) process locking port 3000 on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855127/find-and-kill-process-locking-port-3000-on-mac)