# Git bash "Watching for file changes with StatReloader" stuck and never loads

Tags: python, django, terminal

I have setup a Django project on a virtual environment on my PC. When using the command

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Bit Bash stops doing anything and I have to end the program to start over. I have waited several minutes and when I end the session, a dialogue says:

```
Processes are running in session:
WPID  PID    COMMAND
14904 1534 c:\Users\mine\AppData\Loca
Close anyway?
```

I have looked at every related question to this and tried every solution but I cannot get this to work, on or off the virtual environment.

Not sure if this applies, but I also noticed that in my task manager, `python3.9.exe` appears twice when trying to start the server. The status says running, and the PIDs are different numbers.

Comment: What happens if you type python -V in your terminal?

Comment: Can you try running ```python manage.py test``` or ```python manage.py check``` to see if there's an issue with code (long/infinite running loops etc)

Answer (score 0):

This is because something already running on port `8000`. You can run the Django server by hosting on another port like `8080` but, you can also kill the already running task on the port. Follow the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583562/how-to-kill-a-process-running-on-particular-port-in-linux) to know how exactly you can kill any running process.

Comment: Thank you but changing port did the same thing. Did not fix the issue.

Comment: Did you follow the link? to kill already running ports.

Answer (score 0):

It is highly likely that another application is running using the port 8000. Try running the server using another port, say 8088 and share if the same issue persists.

Comment: The author of the question has already commented that the problem is not caused by another application using the port 8000.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

To run on specific port kill all pids which is showing you on Git bash
(`ps -ef`)... kill them using (`kill -9 pid_no`)... then run your runserver command.

Ex:

```
ps -ef
kill -9 123
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up paying someone to fix this. Here is the conversation I had with the person who found the issue. Hope this helps someone out there.

Also, I noticed sometimes it still does freeze up on the `watching for file changes with StateReloader` until I go the browser and type in `http://localhost:8000/`. Once I do that the rest of the text loads and my browser shows `The install worked successfully! Congratulations!`

```
it works, what did you do?
- We have existing processes on port 8000.I think, you had the server running and kept trying over and over. So, I killed process using 8000 port.
- Next, I run Django project again.
- So, now it's working well.

ok. Can you tell me what you did at the start to make it work? Or was it always working?
- I started git bash session again when I started. Maybe git bash session had problems.
But this was going on for a day, I restarted the computer several times and restarted git bash. Same issue.
You must have done something.
- Sorry, I didn't do anything except restart git bash
how did you restart it?
- right click top of window, select NEW

How do I turn server off?
- press Ctrl + C

- And you didn't quit the server exactly before. Maybe you closed git bash directly and server was still live
- So, we had many 8000 ports.

Ok. How can I see what is on that port now?
- You can use this cli
- netstat -ano | findstr :<PORT>

- We don't have running 8000 port now.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never found solutions to this problem even with killing ports, changing port etc.

[image]

It never display the following part:

```
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

However, when I use the Git Bash terminal include into vscode, it displays the url.

Terminal > New Terminal > then:

[image]

Result :

[image]

Answer (score -1):

python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8080

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score -1):

i had the same annoying problem with git bash on windows when you open it by it self i mean not inside of visual studio code because there this problem dosent appear. so this annoying "Watching for file changes with StatReloader" i find out that when you run "python manage.py runserver" it happens but when you just use "python3 manage.py runserver" then everything is fine. is hard to find any content about this topic but i think that when you dont use python with the number 3 you enter so kind of mode where you are like testing and it is like waiting for you to make changes on the code and see does changes in the web browser with out refresing while with python3 is like ok everything is ready and run so if you make any changes not gonna se it directly

Comment: some basic formatting (just some line breaks at least) would make this much easier to read and understand.