# Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::443 in ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, socket.io, port, kill-process

I am trying to use 443 port for socketio for nodejs app, but it showing 443 already occupied. I tried kill-port 443 to release port 443.

Comment: you can use `netstat` or `ss` to check which process is using port 443

Comment: And please show some of your code ...  Did you try to open this port for ipv4 and ipv6? Then you may be facing an issue with dual stack mode. In the default configuation binding a port for ipv6 also tries to bind it for ipv4. If it is already bound for ipv4 you get an error.

Comment: Hope this help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/32592965/6534338

Comment: When i hit command kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:443) , My firefox browser stopped and ubuntu system ui experience some malfunction for short time. and i retry npm start, which again showing port 443 is engaged, but when i try to kill port again, it showing no process on 443 to kill.