# How to stop Solr servers properly

Tags: solr

I'm using SolrCloud and I wanted to know, if there exists a proper way to stop/shutdown solr servers.
Currently I am using the  **kill**  command in shell to kill the Solr process (using its PID) but it's not very nice !

Is there a way to stop Solr servers knowing their ports for example or something else?

I have found this post : [How to stop solr with command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976261/how-to-stop-solr-with-command-line)

I guess that there are differents ways to stop Solr, can someone recommend me the alternative approaches to do it with SolrCloud?

Thanks.